# How to set cookies with nginx proxy

Tags: nginx, web

I have two server, the one name `page` listen to `127.0.0.1:8080`, the other name `api` listen to `127.0.0.1:8888`. The `api` can set cookie to response.
The nginx config:

```
server {
    listen       8880;
    server_name  127.0.0.1;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

    location /api/v1/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8888/;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
```

so I can request `127.0.0.1:8880/api/v1/user` proxy to `127.0.0.1:8888/user`.
When I use:
`js
$.ajax({
            url: "/api/v1/user/login",
            type: "post",
            dataType: "json",
            data: JSON.stringify({"account": account, "password": password}),
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
            success: function (res) {
                console.log(res.status);
                window.location = "/home"
            }
        })`

to login, the cookie registered on domain:`127.0.0.1`, path:`/api/v1/user`. But I want to registered on domain:`127.0.0.1`, path:`/`, so how can I do it? Is there anyone can help me?

I try to add `proxy_cookie_path /api/v1/user /;` to `location 8888`, but it has no effect